# Complexity of an old Top Coder riddle: Making a number by inserting +

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, reduction, np

This is a follow up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280649/old-top-coder-riddle-making-a-number-by-inserting) (about an old top coder riddle).

> Given a string of digits, find the minimum number of additions required for the string to equal some target number. Each addition is the equivalent of inserting a plus sign somewhere into the string of digits. After all plus signs are inserted, evaluate the sum as usual.
>
> For example, consider "303" and a target sum of 6. The best strategy is "3+03".

I guess (not proved it though) the problem is NP-complete.
What do you think? How would you reduce a well-known NP-complete problem to this problem?

Comment: Reducing it to a known NP-complete problem won't do you any good, as you've only shown that you can make the problem harder. You want to show that you can reduce a known NP-complete problem to your problem (i.e. your problem is NP-hard). Since your problem is obviously in NP, finding this reduction is sufficient to show that your problem is also NP-complete.

Comment: @Michael You should wait a bit longer for someone else to propose a hardness proof for base 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the base is made a parameter, then there is a reduction from subset sum. Let x<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>n</sub>, s > 0 be the instance of subset sum and let S = x<sub>1</sub> + … + x<sub>n</sub>. In base S + 1, let the Top Coder input be

x<sub>1</sub> 0 x<sub>2</sub> 0 … x<sub>n</sub> 0

summing to (S - s) (S + 1) + s.

Much more interesting of course is the hardness of the base 10 case.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the expected result after the number it is clear that this is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem ?

Comment: The partition problem deals with splitting a multiset of integers in two halves. That's not the case here; to begin with, the order of the sequence of digits must be preserved, and more than one "partition" (insertion point of a `+`) might be needed

Comment: @Óscar López, Order of sequences is not problem, just if you partition it into two half make negative a partition which doesn't have first number. (first move wanted result in left side).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution code for the intellectually curious (or lazy).
JavaScript:

```
var A = "12345";

function riddle(s, n) {
 for(var ins=0; ins<s.length; ins++) {
  if( recurse(n, "", s, ins) ) {
   console.log(ins + " insertions");
   break;
  }
 }
}

function recurse(n, t, s, ins) {
 if(ins == 0) {
 // reached the end does it equal the number?
  var temp = (t != "" ? t + " + " : "") + s;
  if( eval(temp) == n ) {
   console.log(temp);
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 } else if(s.length - ins > 0) {
  for(var x=1; x<s.length; x++) {
   var temp = (t != "" ? t + " + " : "") + s.substring(0, x);
   if( recurse(n, temp, s.substring(x), ins-1) ) {
    return true;
   }
  }
 }
 return false;
}

riddle(A, 12345);
riddle(A, 357);
riddle(A, 15);
```

Exponential time, the number of possibilities is 2^(n-1), when n = 3, T(n) = 4; when n = 5, T(n) = 32.

If you consider the number of insertions corresponds with the set size, and the positions of those insertions are the set elements, you can see the relation to subset sum. Also, like Subset Sum the verifier is polynomial time, just summing the set of digits, (the "eval(temp) == n" in the code above).